# Transformation between two rings that switches between the operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that there are two commutative rings $(R_1,+,\times)$ and $(R_2,\oplus,\otimes)$.

Under what conditions does there exist an invertible function $\phi: R_1 \to R_2$ such that

$$
\phi(x \times y) = \phi(x) \oplus \phi(y)
$$

Is there a special name for such a transformation between rings that effectively converts multiplication in one ring to addition in the other?

Comment: This is an isomorphism between the involved multiplicative semi-groups.

Comment: There can never be such a function simply because $0$ exists. Addition is always invertible, but multiplication always has at least one element that fails to be invertible.

Comment: Ah you are right Matt. $\phi(0 \times x) = \phi(0) \oplus \phi(x)$ which implies $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x \in R_1$. This would not be invertible.

Comment: Except for the $0$ ring $(\{0\},+,\cdot)$. There we have $\cdot =+$, and therefore the map sending $0$ ot $0$ does it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens iff both rings are trivial. To see this, take $y=0$. Then your equation says that for every $x\in R_1$ you have

$$\phi(0)=\phi(x\times 0)=\phi(x)\oplus\phi(0)$$

so $\phi(x)=0$. Since $\phi$ is injective, $R_1$ is trivial, so $R_2$ is trivial because $\phi$ is bijective.